# Opencv - external contours of holes

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

So, I want to find every contours of an image and store them in a special format so that the image can be reconstructed in another context.

Currently, I'm retrieving contours with the `RETR_CCOMP` option to get external and internal ones, and when I want to show the shapes, I give these contours to `fillPoly`.

My problem is about holes. When there is a hole in a shape, I want to keep track of them to redraw them. But since I am getting internal contours of the outer shape, when I redraw the hole, it is larger by one pixel.

Here is an explanation of what i would like to have:

[image: example]

in the image one is a sample image. The image two is what `findcontours` gives me (externals in yellow and internals in green).

But I would like to get the contours from the image 3, so that I can redraw the exact same shapes later.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Calculate midpoint of contour, width, height, then reduce 2 px from width and height? OR: (x1,y1) += 1, (x2,y2) -=1, assuming that x1,y1 is left up corner and x2,y2 is right bottom corner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used rectangles for the examples, but I am supposed to do this with any shape. Your solution doesn't work with complex shapes, does it?

Comment: But you may have given me a good solution. Do you think it is okay to compare every points with the center of the contours,  and bring them closer to it?

Comment: You should calculate vector towards center mass, yes. One way to do this to more complex objects (not polygons) could be getting the contour and "zooming out by 2 px" and placing the zoomed mask back in center mass coordinates.

Comment: I think I understand, but how can I "zoom" (scale?) these contours by 2 px?